# How can I organize my Windows directories more efficiently?

Tags: windows-7, windows, unix

I've been using Windows (7 now) for years now, but I can never figure out how to efficiently organize my directories and programs.

I'm finding it difficult to locate and run programs that are spread across multiple partitions due to Windows' lenience on program installation directories. Also, any Unix-like tools I try to install (curl, wget, make, maven, etc.) have no particular installation directory, and end up getting installed directly onto my Windows drive.

Is there any way (or any tools) that I can organize my directories to be somewhat efficient, similar to Unix-style directory structures (i.e. /home, /var, /etc)?

Comment: Documents and downloads are a great place for personal files.  Programs can be found be search on the start me t for the program it's winkey the just type

Comment: @Ramhound I am aware of libraries and such, but I was talking more about the raw structure of the filesystem. For example, Unix has designated folders for different 'sections'of the system (I.e. /dev, /etc, /home), but on Windows you don't get this organised structure - you can have any folder on any drive, with only Windows and Users being the uniform folders.

Comment: Your question is not clear why do you care how anything outside of Your Profile and Program Files is organized?

Comment: I think this is a pretty simple solution. Install your programs in one place, keep your personal files in another place. If you are having trouble finding the shortcut to applications, then you need to create a shortcut in a common place immediately after installation.

Comment: `I'm finding it difficult to locate and run programs that are spread across multiple partitions due to Windows' lenience on program installation directories` - You ultimately control where programs get installed. Blaming Windows for your lack of oversight is being a bit unfair to Windows.

Comment: largely opinion based question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the responsibility is on you to keep your files manageable. After accumulating a lot of files over the years, it can be very difficult to keep track of everything.

Secondly, you may be interested in running Windows Directory Statistics ([WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/)) to get a graphic view of how your files are grouped together. This can help you understand what you have a lot of and might make you want to think about dividing your stuff into multiple categories in the next step.

Thirdly, you probably want to have most things on your computer accessible from a single location. The most viable place for this is your User folder - in your case, C:\Users\%username% . Rename this folder %username%.old, and create a new folder called %username%.

We will rebuild your directory system to be highly organized. Create new folders based on your needs in a logical hierarchical manner. Here is a detailed example.

```
Documents
  -> Schoolwork
    -> Math
    -> English
    -> Art
  -> Work
    -> Business Inc.
      -> 2014 Reports
      -> 2013 Reports
    -> Old Job Inc.
      -> 2012 Reports
  -> Personal Documents
    -> Poetry
    -> Novels
Audio
  -> Music
    -> Techno
      -> Benny Benassi
    -> Country
      -> Tim McGraw
  -> Audio books
    -> Self help
    -> Fiction
Video
  -> TV shows
  -> Movies
    -> Sci-fi
    -> Horror
      -> Saw series
  -> Documentaries
Books
  -> Fantasy
    -> David Edding
  -> Romance
Images
  -> My Artwork
    -> Character Design
  -> Personal Photos
    -> Florida Vacation 2012
  -> Wallpapers
Downloads
```

You will, of course, need to personalize this, but you can see how we want to break things down into logical categories to make it easy to find.

When you install programs install them to C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files(x86) with pretty few exceptions.

Now, to organize what you already have, begin by sorting through your %username%.old folder. Move things into the (more organized!) new location in your %username% folder. Don't be afraid to make more folder if you have to! You might think it's tedious having a thousand folders, but it makes finding things much, much easier.  Move everything out of that old folder and into the new one, and delete the old one when it is empty. It will do you no good to start moving everything and quit half-way, it'll just mean one more place you have to look when you can't find things. So finish the job.

After your old users folder is gone, consider uninstalling programs you have installed in arbitrary places and reinstalling them to your Program Files folders. Most programs save their data in a location other than their install location, or otherwise provide you with an option to keep files and settings during uninstallation. Be careful not to lose important data.

Open WinDirStat and look for large locations that are outside your new user folder. Do they belong with the rest of your documents? Consider moving them to the correct location in your new organized folder, to make them easier to find in the future. If you've been downloading TV shows to your desktop, it's probably a good idea to move them to your User -> Video -> TV Series folder.

Keep searching your system for files that make more sense in your organized directory, and move them. When you create a new file with a program, consider the best place to put it in your directory - if you are a website graphics designer, for instance, your files might go in User -> Documents -> Work -> Job Name -> Mock-ups. If you like making youtube videos, save your files into User -> Video -> My Videos -> Unfinished Youtube. The point is to make everything make sense.

As a last note, KEEP YOUR DOWNLOADS FOLDER EMPTY. When you download something, be it an image or a .torrent or a PDF or a song or a Youtube ripped video or a homework assignment, move it out of the downloads folder and into the proper spot. Download folders are notorious for getting very cluttered, and remember that if you don't deal with it now you'll have to deal with it later, when it's more difficult.

Hopefully this helps you reorganize your system, and if you have any questions or want any advice on specifics, be sure to let me know.